# My Html page is not responsive

Tags: html, css

**I have created the html page . This page is not worked the responsive**

```
My Code

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    body {
    width:1333px;
    height:800px;
    }
    .wrapper {
    width:"100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
    <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have create the html page, provide the html code ,How to display the full text in mobile, tab mode.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Flex does not work in IE9. That's a statement: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
  display: flex;       // others
  display: table-cell; // ie9
  display: -ms-flexbox; //ie10
}
```

> You could use for ie9 and flexbox for others.

Comment: That won't work. "others" will use table-cell since you list it second/last.

Comment: Thanks for your answer